# How to use gsub() to add a string to the front and remove a string from the end at same time?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to match end of given string to a certain pattern. If pattern is there, then I want to remove it and add a certain string to the front of given string.

E.g: If I have `gradesmeanA` and the pattern is `meanA` then I want to add "mean of class A " to the front of `gradesmeanA` and remove `meanA` at the end. So the result should be "mean of class A grades".

I want to use `gsub()` and regular expressions. I want to do this in one step.

What I tried:

```
s1<-gsub(pattern="/\\w /meanA$",replacement="mean of class A / \\w/","gradesmeanA")
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
> s <- "gradesmeanA"
> sub("^(.*?)meanA$", "mean of class A \\1", s, perl=T)
[1] "mean of class A grades"
> sub("^(.*)meanA$", "mean of class A \\1", s)
[1] "mean of class A grades"
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `^` Matches the start of a line.
- `()` Capturing group usually used to capture characters.
- `(.*)meanA$`, all the characters before the last string `meanA` is captured and the last `meanA` is matched.
- In sub or gsub, all the matched characters must be replaced. In our case, all the matched characters (*the whole line*) are replaced by `mean of class A` plus the chaarcters present inside the group index 1.
- `$` Matches the end of a line.

**OR**

An ugly one,

```
> gsub("^(.*?)(mean)(A)$", "\\2 of class \\3 \\1", s, perl=T)
[1] "mean of class A grades"
```

Comment: The `?` and `perl=T` could be omitted.

Comment: @Avinash Raj  Great. Can you explain the regular expression part, so I can learn.

Comment: @Vajira -  you can also get nice regex explanations [here](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=^%28.*%3F%29meanA%24&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: Since only one replacement is performed you can use the `sub` function instead of `gsub`

Comment: @Richard Scriven That site gave nice explanation.